# Understanding the gradients in backpropagation algorithm

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

In the deeplearning.io course by Andrew Ng on coursera, the following gradients are given: [image: Coursera]
Here, a[l] = gl

I fail to understand the gradients obtained here.

If:

```
a[l] = g[l](z[l]),
```

then:

```
da[l] = ∂g[l](z[l])/∂z[l] * dz[l]
=> da[l] = g[l]'(z[l]) * dz[l]
```

But the 1st formula given in the slide is different, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Please watch Andrew Ng's video on **Backpropagation intuition (optional)** from Week3 "Shallow neural networks" to understand the backpropagation derivative.